# Figuring out the nth derivative of a Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Taken from Khan Academy:

The nth derivative of $g$ at $x=0$ is given by $g^{(n)}(0)=\cfrac{\sqrt{n+7}}{n^3}$ for $n\geq1$

What is the coefficient for the term containing $x^2$ in the Maclaurin series of $g$?

The answer says: The quadratic term of the Taylor series centered at $x=0$ is $g^{\prime\prime}(0)\cfrac{x^2}{2!}$

From the given information, $g^{\prime\prime}(0)=\cfrac{\sqrt{9}}{8}=\cfrac{3}{8}$

Then the coefficient of $x^2$ is $\cfrac{3}{8}\cdot\cfrac{1}{2!}=\cfrac{3}{16}$

Why do they use two substituted for the value of n?

Comment: because they want the "second derivative" $g^{''}$, same as $g^{(2)}$.

Comment: $$g^{(n)}(0)\mbox{ is the same as }g{\overbrace{''\cdots''}^{n~times}}(0)$$

Answer (score 0):

The notation $g^{(n)}(x)$ refers to the $n$-th derivative of $g(x)$. Thus, $g''(0)=g^{(2)}(0)$, and (borrowing the nice formatting from Holo in a comment)

$$
g^{(n)}(0)=g{\overbrace{'\!\!\cdots'}^{\text{n times}}}(0)\;.
$$